# How do I post a string to a MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a simple application, which allows me to post a simple string to a Mysql database. But I get an error. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxx.awardspace.net";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (`token`) VALUES (". $_POST["token"].")";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I do this request:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:text/plain" \
   -d \
'token=NEVERLUCKY' \
 'http://myurl.mygamesonline.org/?token=testString123'
```

It returns:

> Error: INSERT INTO tokens (`token`) VALUES ()
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My MYSQL table have a single column which is named token and its type is VARCHAR (200)

Comment: Is `$_POST['token']` populated? You're making an assumption the value is getting to your script. Look at the error, there is *nothing* in the `VALUES()` block.

Comment: You can show database structure?

Comment: what do you mean by that? how do  I make sure my value gets to it ?

Comment: And, yes, you need `VALUES ('". $_POST["token"]."')"` qoute in you query

Comment: I am really new to php, I just put it in the body of my request.

Comment: @Naumov `echo $_POST['token'];` at top of the script. Or `var_dump($_POST)` to print all the `$_POST` variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make something like `$token=$_POST['token'];` and then insert it like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (`token`) VALUES ('$token')";
```

Comment: Okay so php is done, how do I send token to my url of php?

Answer (score 0):

Add a basic check before you attempt to run the query and make sure the value is quoted properly:

```
if(isset($_POST['token'])) {

    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (`token`) VALUES ('$token')"; // no need to concatenate and make sure the quotes are correct

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
<br >
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '&quot;', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b>/srv/disk3/1965965/www/ssssball.mygamesonline.org/index.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br >

Comment: That error is not from the code that I posted here, it is in your original code somewhere.